# python3 arparse error regarding argument being missing

Tags: arguments, parameter-passing, argparse

here is a code that takes one positional argument and tow optional arguments

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
from typing import NamedTuple, Dict, List
import csv


class Args(NamedTuple):
    rna: str
    ins: List
    dell: int

def get_args() -> Args:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='translating mRNA', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('rna', metavar='RNA seq', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--ins', '-i', type=list, help='add the insertion position and the base to test its frameshift effect')
    parser.add_argument('--dell', '-d', type=int, help='add the position of the deleted base to test its frameshift effect')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.rna and not args.ins and not args.dell:
        return Args(args.rna)
    elif args.rna and args.ins:
        return Args(args.rna, ins=args.ins)
    elif args.rna and args.dell:
        return Args(args.rna, dell=args.dell)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Invalid arguments provided')


def main():
    args = get_args()
    codons = codon_dict()
    rna = args.rna
    ins = args.ins
    dell = args.dell
    protein = translator(rna)
    print(f'protein_original:\n{protein}')
    if args.ins and not args.dell:
        ins_mut_rna = list(rna)
        ins_mut_rna.insert(ins[0] + 1, ins[1])
        ins_mut_protein = translator(ins_mut_rna)
        print(f'frameshift protein\n{ins_mut_protein}')
    elif args.dell and not args.ins:
        dell_mut_rna = list(rna)
        dell_mut_rna.pop(dell + 1)
        dell_mut_protein = translator(dell_mut_rna)
        print(f'frameshift\n{dell_mut_protein}')
    elif args.ins and args.dell:
        if args.ins[0] > args.dell:
            ins_dell_rna = list(rna)
            ins_dell_rna.insert(ins[0] + 1, ins[1])
            ins_dell_rna.pop(dell + 1)
            ins_dell_prot = translator(ins_dell_rna)
        elif args.dell > args.ins:
            dell_ins_rna = list(rna)
            dell_ins_rna.pop(dell + 1)
            dell_ins_rna.insert(ins[0] + 1, ins[1])
            dell_ins_prot = translator(dell_ins_rna)
            print(f'frameshift protein\n{dell_ins_prot}')


def translator(rna) ->str:
    prot = []
    steps = [i for i in range(0, len(rna), 3)]
    rna_codons = []
    for step in steps:
        rna_codons.append(rna[step:step + 3])
    start = rna_codons.index('AUG')
    rna_codons = rna_codons[int(start):]
    for codon in rna_codons:
        if codon in codons:
            if codons[codon] == 'Stop':
                break
            prot.append(codons[codon])
    return ''.join(prot)


def codon_dict() ->Dict:
    mydict = {}
    with open('codon_table.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for rows in reader:
            k = rows[0]
            v = rows[2]
            mydict[k] = v
        return mydict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I try to pass this command on terminal here is what I get
command:

```
python3 prot.py AUGUUUAUG -d 4 -i '4 T'
```

error:

```
line 22, in get_args
    return Args(args.rna, ins=args.ins)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Args.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'del
```

I tried to modify the the if, elif in the get_args(), but it didn't work, also googled the error but didn't find a solution, asked chat-gpt, but its solutuon also didn't work, pls help.

Comment: It's `Args` that's complaining, not `argparse`

Answer (score 0):

With the parser you define and the sample input the `args` namespace is:

```
In [13]: import shlex
In [14]: alist = shlex.split("AUGUUUAUG -d 4 -i '4 T'"); alist
Out[14]: ['AUGUUUAUG', '-d', '4', '-i', '4 T']

In [15]: args = parser.parse_args(alist)
In [16]: args
Out[16]: Namespace(rna='AUGUUUAUG', ins=['4', ' ', 'T'], dell=4)
```

Note that the `-i` string, '4 T' has been split into a list for single characters.  That's what `list('4 T')` does.  You probably did not want that `type` function.

But the error is a `TypeError`, produced by the line

```
Args(args.rna, ins=args.ins)
```

It's saying that the `Args` is missing a positional argument, the `dell`.  This is not a `argparse` error, which would display the usage and exit.

What are you trying to do here?  Learn `argpare`, `typing` or something else?

This is not the kind of error that other people would make, so a wild internet or AI search is unlikely to help.  You need to read more about `typing`.  I'd also suggest practicing with `argparse` without the `typing` layer. Mixing two things doesn't help you learn either.

### typing

With your typing imports and `Args':

```
In [20]: class Args(NamedTuple):
    ...:     rna: str
    ...:     ins: List
    ...:     dell: int
    ...:
```

Correct usage:

```
In [21]: Args('one',[1,2],4)
Out[21]: Args(rna='one', ins=[1, 2], dell=4)
```

Your error:

```
In [22]: Args('one',[1,2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 1
----> 1 Args('one',[1,2])

TypeError: Args.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dell'
```

expressions like

```
Args(args.rna, dell=args.dell)
```

suggest that you think the positional/optionals definition in `argparse` carry over to this `Args` class.  That somehow you can give one `rna` parameter, and treat the others as keyword parameters with default values.  The definition of a `NamedTuple` is distinct from the definition of a `argparse` parser.  The parser produces a `argparse.Namespace` object.  It is not a `NamedTuple`.

The init signature for an `Args` instance is:

```
Init signature: Args(rna: str, ins: List, dell: int)
```

For the parser, usage is:

```
In [27]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--ins INS] [--dell DELL] RNA seq
```

With the above `args` namespace object, I can create an `Args` instance with:

```
In [30]: Args(**vars(args))
Out[30]: Args(rna='AUGUUUAUG', ins=['4', ' ', 'T'], dell=4)
```

With other parser inputs:

```
In [32]: args = parser.parse_args(['AUG', '-d', '4'])

In [33]: args
Out[33]: Namespace(rna='AUG', ins=None, dell=4)

In [34]: Args(**vars(args))
Out[34]: Args(rna='AUG', ins=None, dell=4)

In [35]: args = parser.parse_args(['AUG'])

In [36]: args
Out[36]: Namespace(rna='AUG', ins=None, dell=None)

In [37]: Args(**vars(args))
Out[37]: Args(rna='AUG', ins=None, dell=None)
```

typing does not do any runtime checking of the parametre types:

```
In [38]: Args(2,2,3)
Out[38]: Args(rna=2, ins=2, dell=3)
```

So I don't know what you hoped to accomplish with the `typing` imports.  It doesn't add anything to the `argarse` processing or error checking.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. You don't need to declare type `Args`. You can use the return value of `parse_args()` directly
2. Your `if/elif/else` block at the end of `get_args()` is too complicated and not necessary.
3. Speculation: Given the arguments `-d '4 T'`, I suspect you want a list `[4, 'T']`, not `['4', ' ', 'T']`, which your current code produces. To fix it, I created a short function called `parse_ins` and use it in place of `type`.
4. Speculation: The ins and dell are optional. They are `None` if not specified.

With that, here is my version of `get_args()`:

```py
def parse_ins(text):
    """Parse the ins.
    
    For example: '4 T' --> [4, 'T']
    """
    out = text.split()
    out[0] = int(out[0])
    return out


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="translating mRNA",
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument("rna", metavar="RNA seq", type=str)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--ins",
        "-i",
        type=parse_ins,
        help="add the insertion position and the base to test its frameshift effect",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--dell",
        "-d",
        type=int,
        help="add the position of the deleted base to test its frameshift effect",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```